# Jquery ajax call always returns error on ASP.NET web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

I've been trying to make a jquery ajax call to an ASP.NET web service from a php application. I've tried with jsonp but the result is always the same. It always gives me an error result, and when I tried to see the error, it only gives me a blank result. I've tried adding and deleting attributes of the ajax call to see if it works, but still not result. As for the web service, I'm 100% sure it is working fine.

So here is the code for my ajax call :

```
function submitClicked(){
        var url = "http://localhost/MyWebService/service1.asmx/HelloWorld";
        $.ajax( url, {
                dataType: "jsonp", 
                type:'POST',  
                success: function (data) {  
                    successCallback(data);  
                },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log("error");
                }

        });
}
```

And here's my web service code in VB.NET :

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Sub HelloWorld()
    Context.Response.Clear()
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    Context.Response.Flush()
    Context.Response.Write("{""success"":1}")
End Sub
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out what was my mistake.

To help anyone out there who has the same problem, I added one more parameter to my web service methods which is a callback parameter, like so :

```
 <WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Sub HelloWorld(ByVal Test As String, ByVal callback As String)
    Dim json As String = "{""success"":1}"
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append(callback + "(")
    sb.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json))
    sb.Append(");")
    Context.Response.Clear()
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    Context.Response.Write(sb.ToString)
    Context.Response.End()
End Sub
```

And as for the ajax function, this is how it is :

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/MyWebService/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
                crossDomain:true,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: false,
                data:{Test:'This is a test'},
                success:function(data){
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if(json.success == 1) {
                         alert("success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         alert("failed");
                    }
                },
                error:function(error){
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
```

Hope it helps. Thank  you.